# How to use SumConvergence to judge whether this series is convergent?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{b}{a_{n}}\right)^{n}$

where Limit $\left[a_{n}, n \rightarrow\right.$ Infinity $]=a$, and $a>0 \& \& b>0 \& \& a_{n}>0 $

No results can be obtained with the following code.

```
Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0 && 
  ForAll[n, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers, a[n] > 0] && 
  Limit[a[n], n -> Infinity] == a, 
   SumConvergence[(b/a[n])^n, n]]
```

> SumConvergence $\left[\left(\frac{b}{a[n]}\right)^{n}, n\right]$

Comment: Your condition `Subscript[a, n] > 0` is incompetent. It should be `ForAll[n,n\[Element]PositiveIntegers, a[n]>0]` instead of. I think `SumConvergence` does not handle quantifiers.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, it still cannot be calculated.

Comment: One more mistake. A sequence is a function defined on positive integers. Therefore, the notation `a[n]` should be used, not `Subscript[a, n]`.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks. You're right. I've edited the original question.

Comment: No, notation a[n] should be only used in the code, in latex a_n is correct.

Comment: Perhaps, Mathematica is unable to solve this problem.  Documentation for `SumConvergence` shows no such examples.

Comment: @user64494 and  Валерий, `Subscript` can be used to represent sequence in _Mathematica_, for example: `eqn = Subscript[a, n + 1] - 2 Subscript[a, n] == 1; sol = RSolve[eqn, Subscript[a, n], n][[1]]`. The real problem here is, as mentioned by bbgodfrey, `SumConvergence` probably cannot handle the problem at least now.

Comment: `a > 0` and `a[n] > 0` seem contradictory on a code/symbolic level. For instance, if `a = 2`, what does `2[n] > 0` mean? If you have an interpretation, do you really think that is what is going to be applied? (Just because humans can abuse notation and get away with it among themselves, does not mean computer systems will do it. Secondly, I don't think the condition `Limit[c[n], n -> Infinity] == a` will be applied mathematically (using `c[n]` in place of `a[n]`). You could try converting it to an algebraic statement, but I haven't had much success with that in general.

Comment: @Michael E2 In this problem, $a_{n}$ is a function of n. when n tends to infinity, the limit of $a_{n}$ is $a$, and both $a_{n}$ and $a$ belong to positive real numbers. Besides, $a_{n}$ has no other meaning.

Comment: The symbol `a` in the two expressions `a` and `a[n]` are the same to Mathematica. Try `a[n] == a /. a -> 2`. So the semantics of the code does correspond precisely with your intended meaning. Since Mathematica does not solve your problem or the one in which `a[n]` tends to a different letter `L`, say, it's hard to say whether the using `a` in two ways prevents a solution. Heads  (part `0`) are sometimes treated differently than arguments (parts $\ge$ `1`). But it's safer to use different symbols for your limit and the head of the function.

Comment: Aside: The abuse of notation in mathematics, $a_n \rightarrow a$, is historical and still traditional (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition)). ***I*** understand what you mean. Thinking of sequences as functions of an integer is relatively recent, where $a$ denotes the function ${\Bbb N}\rightarrow{\Bbb R}$, $a_n$ denotes the value of $a$ in ${\Bbb R}$ at a value $n$ in ${\Bbb N}$. But the tradition continues, esp. in lower-level courses. Not everyone follows it, but everyone is used to it. However, one generally has not able to follow it in CS.

Comment: @Michael E2 Thank you for your comments. I will pay attention to choosing the appropriate symbol in MMA in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an extended comment more than an answer.  In general, Mathematica returns a function unevaluated without an error message when it is unable to provide an answer.  I believe that this is the case in this question.  So, I tried a succession of easier cases.

```
Assuming[a > 0 && c > 0, SumConvergence[(a + n^-c)^n, n]]
```

which is equivalent to `a[n] = a + n^-c` and `b = 1`, also returns unevaluated.  If `c` is replaced by a specific value, for instance,

```
Assuming[a > 0, SumConvergence[(a + n^-(1/30))^n, n]]
(* a < 1 *)
```

it produces the expected answer.  On the other hand,

```
Assuming[a > 0, SumConvergence[(a + n^-(1/31))^n, n]]
```

returns unevaluated.  I find this surprising.  Next, replace `a` by a number very near `1`.

```
SumConvergence[(999999999999999999999999/1000000000000000000000000 + 
    n^-(1/1000000))^n, n]
(* True *)
```

which is correct.  But,

```
SumConvergence[(999999999999999999999999/1000000000000000000000000 + 
    n^-(1/10000000))^n, n]
```

crashes the kernel, and

```
SumConvergence[(999999999999999999999999/1000000000000000000000000 + 
    n^-(1/1000000000))^n, n]
```

again returns unevaluated.  For completeness, these computations were performed on Mathematica 13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021), run on Windows 11.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your answer is very clear. After reading the answers and comments,  I also think that SumConvergence probably cannot handle the problem. By the way, in v11.3, `Assuming[a > 0, SumConvergence[(a + n^-(1/31))^n, n]]`, result:` (* a < 1 *)`.

Comment: @lotus2019 Now, that is strange.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: mma v11.3 on win7 system.

Comment: @lotus2019 I may explore this further when I have time, using earlier versions of Mathematica.  Perhaps, there is a bug here.  The version I used now is added to the end of my answer.